# How to properly compare data of any type in C with pointers and type conversion to char

Tags: c, pointers, types

I know that C is not a language that easily allows developers to create generic typed functions.  However, as a learning exercise I am trying to write a function that allows a user to pass an array of any data type (i.e. `void`) and a scalar of any data type (i.e. `void`).  The purpose of the function is to walk through the array with a pointer and compare the scalar to the value in the array index and see if they match.  In order to do this, I convert the scalar and the array into a `char` and use `strcmp` from the `string.h` library.  The function looks like the example below.

```
void find_vector_indices(void *vec, void *value, size_t num_bytes, size_t arr_size) {
    char compare;
    char *val = (char *) value;
    char *dst;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        dst = (char *) vec + (i * num_bytes);
        compare = strcmp(dst, val);
        if (compare == 0) printf("Strings Match\n");
    }
}
```

In the main function if I have the following code using integers, the above function works just fine and prints `Strings Match` twice, just as I would expect.

```
    int a[3] = {3, 2, 3};
    int b = 3;
    find_vector_indices(a, &b, sizeof(int), 3);
```

However, if I modify the main function to be a float array and a float scalar like so, the function no longer works.

```
float a[3] = {3.1, 2.2, 3.1};
flat b = 3.1;
find_vector_indices(a, &b, sizeof(float), 3);
```

I am assuming this has something to do with how float and integer values are represented in memory.  However, as best i know it, both consume 4 bytes of memory and should be correctly represented as character strings, which I believe are correctly pointed to in the pointer arithmetic of this function.  The solution is probably very simple, but it is escaping me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The bytewise equality criterion you are trying to implement is not well matched to C semantics for structures and unions.  These may contain padding bytes that are not semantically meaningful, and whose values are not required to be preserved or copied by various operations.  The values of such bytes will nevertheless be taken into account by your comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcmp()` is for comparing *strings* (NUL-terminated sequence of characters), not arbitrary binary data. Use `memcmp()` instead.

Instead of

```c
compare = strcmp(dst, val);
```

You should use

```c
compare = memcmp(dst, val, num_bytes);
```

In little-endian machine, the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th bytes of small `int` such as 2 or 3 will be zero, so it will work as the string terminator and your code seem working.

On the other hand, the `float` value `3.1` will be represented as `0x40466666` (according to [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)). This doesn't contain 0x00 bytes, so `strcmp()` has less chance to seem working.

---

Also the type of `compare` should be `int`, not `char`. `strcmp()` and `memcmp()` returns `int` and its range is not specified. (just specified to be positive, negative, or zero, according to the result of comparision). Therefore, there maybe some chance to misunderstand unmatch as match due to the truncation.

Comment: Thank you.  I rarely use C and am trying to beef up my skills with this language.  I was not even aware of the existence of `memcmp`, but yes, it make much more sens to use this, then to use `strcmp`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72631525/2410359) good answer:

**Use consistent types**

```
// for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
```

**"see if they match"?**

Even with fixed suggested by @MikeCAT,

`0.0 == -0.0` is true, yet via `find_vector_indices()` would report they differ as they have the same *value*, but different bit patterns.  This can also happen with other floating point encodings and pointers.

```
float a[1] = {-0.0};
float b = 0.0;
find_vector_indices(a, &b, sizeof b, 1);
```

See also `struct` concerns [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72631453/how-to-properly-compare-data-of-any-type-in-c-with-pointers-and-type-conversion/72631918#comment128299294_72631453).

**Alternative**

Rather than use `memcmp(), strcmp()`, etc., pass in a compare function `int cmp(const void *, const void *)` and return the first zero compare address.

```
// Illustrative untested code.
void *find_vector_match(const void *vec, const void *value, size_t element_size,
    size_t arr_n, int (cmp)(const void *, const void *)) {
 
  while (arr_n > 0) {
    arr_n--;
    if (cmp(vec, value) == 0) {
      return (void *) vec;
    }
    vec = (const unsigned char*)vec + element_size;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This is great information, thank you.  Just out of curiosity, why do you recommend passing a compare function to the `find_vector_match` function as opposed to hard coding it in the function?

Comment: @Jon: Greater flexibility.  It allows you to create type-aware comparison functions so you can deal with issues like padding bytes, or otherwise use a more reliable method than a simple bitwise compare.  It also follows the paradigm established by the [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) library function.